# Meteor app with iron-router gives error 'Cannot find module connect

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a `meteor` app, `version 0.8.2`, which has been working up till today (July 1, 2014).  When starting it today, it gives an error

```
cannot find module home/randy/Desktop/test.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm/iron- router/main/node_modules/connect
```

I have created another simple app to remove any module conflicts and get the same error.  I created the test project (files below) as follows...

```
mrt create test
cd test
mrt add iron-router
```

**Note** - I did add the connect module independently of iron-router and it did not resolve the issue.  I also updated the smart.json to use version 0.6.4 of iron-router and ran 'mrt install' and 'mrt add iron-router'.  These did not resolve the issue.

My files are as follows (and are all in the root of my test app)...

**smart.json**

```
{
  "packages": {
    "iron-router": {}
  }
}
```

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'hello'
    })
});
```

**test.html**

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> yield}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably something like you lost your internet connection while it was installing.

Delete the npm and build directory directory

```
cd packages/iron-router/
rm -rf .build
rm -rf .npm
cd ../../
meteor
```

This would then force it to re-install connect. This bit needs an internet connection too.

Iron router's connect is scoped to the iron-router package. If the connect here installs successfully, its probably from another package or from the way you tried to add it in, which you might want to undo.

Comment: That fixed the error. Not sure why the error started as I was not trying to update or add any packages until after the error, but this worked. As for adding connect, you can run 'mrt add connect' and it will add it as a package (not part of iron-router, but as a package)